# How to use alphabets on keypad in Phone App? - Samsung Galaxy 3 I5801

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo, contacts, samsung-galaxy-apollo, phone-app

When I select Phone app and go to keypad tab, on keys I see alphabets besides each number key. How to use them?

I suppose it should find a contact already in my contacts. When I type key 7 twice it types two 7s and it doesn't show any contact starting from Q.

Note: I've upgraded to Froyo using steps mentioned at  http://theandroidfans.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-install-android-22-froyo-latest.html

Comment: The downvote seems a bit harsh, anyone care to explain what they didn't like about this question?

Comment: I agree - I upvoted just now to contradict the down vote ( down votes sometimes are a bit to easily assigned, in my opinion ). Especially when no explanation is given ...

Comment: @GAThrawn! @Edelcom! Thanks friends. And many thanks to the person who down-voted. I earned 3 reputation points in all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Just now I realized how it works. If I have a contact whose name is starting with `QAP` (for example ;). Otherwise I don't think in the world any name would start like this), then I should type `727` and it will bring that contact on top.

Basically it works as if T9 is activated for the keypad and that is why it doesn't show names starting from `Q` when I press 7 twice. I hope it helps others.

Comment: ok, but you can't bring up the first name starting with a Q , or an R , this way ? Correct ?

Comment: Agreed! The example problem I gave still couldn't be solved as I was trying the wrong way. Though wasn't the main question `How to use alphabets on keypad in Phone App`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't : press the 7, and it will show ( on my Galaxy S ) the first phone number with a 7 , next to that field is a downwards arrow.

Pressing that arrow will display a popup selection, with at the top the same number already selected ( the first with a 7 ), and underneath the first contact starting with a P - scrolling down shows all contact up to and including contacts with an S.

But if you want a contact, why not use the Contacts tab, you can search there and to the right of my screen is the complete alphabet. Pressing one of these letters, will jump to the first contact name starting with that letter.

Comment: Look at my answer. I just realized that. I agree that pressing one letter directly jumps to the first contact starting with that letter. I was just asking for curiosity as I thought that, those alphabets would not have been provided uselessly.

Comment: And also I had a phone with keypad earlier. So that is the familiar way to me. Now that I know this, I might use it more often than the other. Don't know!

Comment: @Ismail The letters are there so that you can map them to numbers; for example, 555-ANDROID is really 555-263-7643.  You can type the "ANDROID" by looking at the letters, and it will come out as the numbers.

Comment: Correct @Matthew! That's one more use of it apart from searching into contacts.